# Keras: custom objective function, where to put the derivative

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, loss-function, objective-function

I am trying to modify a bit the loss function of my convent and I have some questions from the implementation side.

I already know how to create a custom loss function in Keras, and how to call it. But I still do not have clear where to include the derivative of the function.

Let's say that my new loss function is:

Loss = cross-entropy + f(x)

where f(x) = x**2.

Where should I include f'(x)=2x so that it is used in the back-prop step?
Does Keras automatically do that? Or should I define this explicitly in some part?

Thanks for any hint on this, since I do not know how to do it.

Chuan.

Answer (score 2):

Loss must be a function of a) your networks output and b) correct labels.
Having loss = Summ(a,b) makes your network minimize both a) and b).
minimizing x**2 brings x close to zero;
minimizing softmax().. since softmax(x) is not a loss function, is defined only for a vector X, and helps make a vector summ up to 1, you cant really minimize it. I guess you are mixing concepts here.

Softmax is an activation function, and its output can be used to compute loss, eg. logloss

Comment: thank you for your (fast) answer.

You are right, I made a mistake, I wanted to say cross-entropy, not softmax (I do not know why I put softmax btw). I corrected it in the question.

Well,for f(x) it was just an example of a differentiable function, I do not actually want to minimize that function